# Scan Barcode from Mobile Camera by using Webapplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Implement it from

> https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/

and that is work properly in desktop but not work/scan in mobile, 
i have no idea how to solve it Is there any way to solve this problem

```
<canvas style="height: 35%; width: 100%"></canvas>
                    <ul></ul>
                    <script src="~/WebCam_Js/qrcodelib.js"></script>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/WebCam_Js/webcodecamjs.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var txt = "innerText" in HTMLElement.prototype ? "innerText" : "textContent";
                        var arg = {
                            resultFunction: function (result) {
                                debugger;
                                document.getElementById('BillNo').value = result.code;
                                document.getElementById('clickButton').click();
                                document.getElementById('BillNo').focus();
                                document.getElementById('myButton').click();
                            }
                        };
                        new WebCodeCamJS("canvas").init(arg).play();
        </script>
```

Comment: Well, the best way to solve it is to troubleshoot your code, and maybe even post something here, From these 2 lines of text, we are not able to help you.

Comment: same as https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/